# What's the domestic to international connection procedure at Stansted airport?

Tags: transit, airports, stn

When making an international to international connection at Stansted, you clear immigration, exit into the arrivals hall and then clear departures security.

But what is the procedure if arriving on a domestic flight and wishing to connect to an international one?

Comment: This seems to be the wrong way round: from a domestic flight you would go to the arrivals hall and from there to international departures. If you are in transit between two international flights, you would stay airside (unless you have a visa and there is a long stopover).

Comment: @WeatherVane Wrong. There's no international connections corridor at STN (only at LHR, LGW and MAN): having done international to international several times, you definitely have to go through the arrivals hall

Comment: I am amazed it is so. [This webpage](http://www.stanstedairport.com/at-the-airport/airport-transfers/) tells you how to transfer from domestic to international flights. "If you are connecting from a UK flight to an international flight you will need to pass through special immigration control points where you may be asked to show your passport."

Comment: @WeatherVane That's what I'm wondering about, as it'd be remarkable as the Uk doesn't do Exit checks

Comment: the "web page" in question is total rubbish, and very general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is based on my experience arriving on a domestic flight at Stansted in early April 2018:

If you have baggage to claim, you will have to re-enter the departures area through security like a normal passenger. There's only a single domestic baggage reclaim belt at Stansted and certainly no special transit corridor or similar.

However, domestic arrivals are routed through the departure lounge at Stansted, so if you had only hand luggage, you could simply head to the gate for your connecting flight, making sure to leave plenty of time in case your boarding pass not having been scanned at security poses an issue. Note that many airlines reserve the right to check your hand luggage, so I wouldn't rely on this to make a tight connection.

Comment: Ryanair will place large hand bags in the belly of the aircraft once on the tarmac, unless you bought Priority boarding

Comment: Also, if domestics arrive through the departure lounge, how do you reach domestic baggage claim? IME, the only way out from departures is through a special exit where staff uses your boarding pass to check you out, before dropping you off at the international baggage claim

Comment: @Coke My experience was as follows:
Arrived on a domestic Ryanair flight from Edinburgh, entered the terminal building off the tarmac through a door marked "Domestic Arrivals only", and followed signs for "Domestic Arrivals". I was clearly passing through the departures area (people queueing up to board flights, gate numbers, shops, etc.) and eventually arrived at Domestic baggage reclaim, which was a single belt with no obvious alternative entrance other than through the departures area.

Comment: So if I have a booking on the same ticket, will my bag be checked through?

Comment: @gparyani That depends entirely on the airline. I know Ryanair check bags through at Stansted if you buy a connecting ticket through them (eg Edinburgh to Bari)